# When my subset of $G$ containing identity and elements of same order is a subgroup of $G$?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

I check if subset $H$ is a subgroup on the following way:

1. $H$ is nonempty
2. $H$ is closed under binary operation of G
3. The identity $e$ of $G$ is in $H$
4. For all $a\in H$, $a^{-1}\in H$.

So I have that $e\in H$, so 3. and 1. hold.

Next, elements in $H$ have same order, so there exists $k$ such that $a^k = e$, for every $a\in H$.

If $a\in H$ then  $a^{-1}\in H$ because inverse of element has same order as that element, and 4. holds.

I have troubles with 2. I proceed at this way:
Pick two elements in $H$, $x$ and $y$. I know that $x^k = e$ and $y^k = e$. I want to show that $H$ is closed and goal of this task is to find $k$ when this happens.

My group $G$ is abelian, but I don't know how to use this here.

How to proceed further?

Comment: What is your $H$ exactly? - For abelain $G$, the map $G\to G$, $x\mapsto x^k$ is a homomoprhism, and it seems you want $H$ to be its kernel (which is however not the case with a direct interpretation of your question title if the common order is not prime)

Comment: This is not true if $k$ is not prime. If $k=mn$, $a^m \in H$ but $\operatorname{ord}(a^m) = n$.

Comment: $H$ contains all elements of $G$ that have order k and identity.

Comment: Do you know that $H$ contains every element of $G$ with order $k$? If not this won't work. Consider $H = \{0,1,4\}\subseteq \mathbb{Z}_5$. Here $H$ satisfies conditions 1,3 and 4 but not 2. But every element (except $0$) has order $5$ since it's a group of prime order.

Comment: This is not clear at all.  What are your assumptions, exactly, and what are you asking?

Comment: If $G$ is abelian and if $x$ and $y$ have order $k$, then $(xy)^k = x^ky^k = e\cdot e =e$

Comment: Then this is true for all $k$?

Comment: @likeAvirgin It's not. See player3236's comment. For example in $\mathbb{Z}_6$ the element $1$ has order $6$ but $1+1 = 2$ has not (it's order is $3$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G$ be an abelian group and $k$ a positive integer. Let
$$H=\{e\}\cup \{\,g\in G\mid \operatorname{ord}(g)=k\,\}. $$

- If $k$ is prime, then $H$ is the kernel of the homomorphism $G\to G$, $x\mapsto x^k$ and therefore a subgroup (and in fact a normal subgroup)
- If $k=1$, then $H$ is trivial and hence a subgroup.
- If  no element of $G$ has order $k$, then $H$ is trivial and hence a subgroup.
- In all other cases, $H$ is not a subgroup: As we are not in the third bullit point,  we can pick $h\in H$ with $\operatorname{ord}(h)=k$. As we are not in the first or second bullit point, $k$ is neither prime nor $=1$, hence it is composite. So $k=rs$ with integers $r,s>1$. Then $\operatorname{ord}(h^r)=s$, which is neither $k$ nor $1$ and hence $h^r\notin H$.

Comment: Where we use that $G$ is abelian?